# ChkDsk Timout during repair attempt

Tags: hard-drive, timeout, sata, chkdsk

I started `chkdsk H: /F /R /X` as admin on a SATA harddisk (WD Caviar Green 1TB) that I mounted using an USB adapter.

After a while the operation timed out with the message

```
The specified I/O on \Device\Harddisk3\DR60 was not
completed before the time-out period expired.
```

The drive has severe problems but I managed to get most of the data from it copying them in small chunks. I want to repair it now using chkdsk to see if I can et a couple more files from it. The drive has photos of a friend of mine and they are important to her.

My question is if there is any way I can repair the harddrive to the point where I can recover the files I may have missed.

Is everything done that can be done once chkdsk times out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Since the drive is damaged, it has bad sectors and all I/O operations fail on those bad sectors. `chkdsk` can only repair logical filesystem issues, not physical issues.